# How to replace crosstab cell's value with a string

Tags: crosstab, cognos

I have column fact, it can carry some difference values:

```
 - Positive values - real values, need to be outputted as is
 - 0 is null, output as is
 - -1 - special value. Need to ouput "VAC" string in cell.
 - -2 - special value. Need to output "SICK" string in cell.
```

I tried to do it with editing dimension, i replace it with:

```
case 
    when [BaseEmp].[FACT_VALUE] = -1 then 'VAC'
    when [BaseEmp].[FACT_VALUE] = -2 then 'SICK'
    else to_char([BaseEmp].[FACT_VALUE])
end
```

But now I see error: ORA-01722 invalid number (i think, because strings cannot be aggregated). In column properties I select "min" as aggregate function.

How to replace my special values with strings?

Comment: More examples of what you actually want would be very helpful.  Do you want to change the values **after** aggregation?  You may need to use a subquery to get your desired results, and then use that resultset for your crosstab.

Comment: I want to replace values after aggregation (because it can't aggregate strings). I modified query to get strings, but crosstab can't output strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to change value to VAC, SICK etc.
You need to change DISPLAYED value.

1. Unlock the padlock in RS.
2. Select text in your cell
3. Set text source to "Report Expression"
4. Write expression like

---

```
CASE
    WHEN cellValue() = -1 THEN 'VAC'
    WHEN cellValue() = -2 THEN 'SICK'
    WHEN cellValue() = 0 THEN ''
    ELSE cellValue()
END
```

Comment: Learned something new here. Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 0):

I tried thinking of a work around regarding your problem. I'm not really sure what you crosstab looks like but considering your parameters above, try creating a data item which holds your case condition for your fact. 
Ex.

```
case 
    when [BaseEmp].[FACT_VALUE] = -1 then 'VAC' <--- this will produce Any Error Characters
    when [BaseEmp].[FACT_VALUE] = -2 then to_char([BaseEmp].[FACT_VALUE]/0) <--- this will produce Missing Value Characters
    else to_char([BaseEmp].[FACT_VALUE]) <---- as is
end
```

Then set the data item's Data Format to number and set the values for the properties as follows:
[image]

Kindly give this a try and hopefully it can somehow resolve you problem. Cheers!

Comment: Ok, I will try this method. But I have more that 2 string values. I Will try to use other characters there.

Comment: Thanks for giving it a try. The string values you can set is very limited because it relies on the values character properties. Yes you can also try producing values that can trigger the other value characters not used. Goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

Nikita Kuhta checkout Alexey's Baturin's answer. I think it's the appropriate approach. Just one thing if you unlock and select the text in the cell, all of the cell values will be selected and affected by the report expression. You might have several columns or other fact items in the crosstab. If that's the case, what you can do is

1. Unlock the Report.
2. Select the crosstab cell/intersection you want to change.
3. Set the Define Content to Yes.
4. Drag a Layout Calculation in the crosstab cell/intersection, then insert    your case statement.

Thanks to a friend who told be about the define contents. :D